# How to return an array from a function and loop through it?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

```
#include <iostream>

int* fib(int);

int main()
{
    int count;
    std::cout<<"enter number up to which fibonacci series is to be printed"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>count;
    int *p=new int[count];
    p=fib(count);
    int i;
    for(i<0;i<=count;i++)
        std::cout<<p[i]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int* fib(int d)
{
    int *ar=new int[d];
    int p=-1,q=1,r;
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<=d;j++)
    {
        r=p+q;
        ar[j]=r;
        p=q;
        q=r;
    }
    return ar;
    delete ar;
}
```

Why am I not able to print the whole array of Fibonacci series in this way?

Comment: What problems are you seeing? Compiler errors? If so, which ones? Unexpected results? If so, what results were you expecting and what do you get instead?

Comment: well, where to start... first, what does it mean "not able" - what happens? Also, there are some problems in your code: 1) you don't need to allocate the array in main - it causes memory leak as you immediately override the pointer; 2) the `delete ar` statement in `fib()` is never executed as it is after return, but if it where you'd lost the data you've just computed

Comment: no error is coming.but i don't get the series.can you please check it on your compiler?i am using gcc.

Comment: If you are "done with this question", please accept an answer and ask a new question.

Comment: done with this question.how can i extend this program to print fibonacci series between two numbers?please give some idea

Comment: When you are done with the question, try and pick an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several issues with your code

```
for(i<0;i<=count;i++)
```

should actually be

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
```

and

```
for(j=0;j<=d;j++)
```

must read

```
for(j=0;j<d;j++)
```

And remove the line

```
delete ar;
```

since it does not have any effect after the `return` statement. Additionally you can get rid of the instantiation

```
int *p=new int[count];
```

in `main()` since this is done in your `fib` function also.  As it stands, you leak the memory you just allocated.

Comment: @David well this can be discussed. I can not read this out of the problem spec ;-) It gives the first `n` numbers starting with 0, 1. Thus it all depends on the definition of `fib(n)`.

Comment: the loops are fine so long as n+1 elements are allocated

Comment: i have done all that you have said but couldn't get the series.can you please it on your compiler?

Comment: done with this question.how can i extend this program to print fibonacci series between two numbers?please give some idea

Comment: @Gautam: you are supposed to learn how to think.  You should be able to work out how to do it (it arguably only takes one call to your existing `fib()` function - you just alter the way you do the printing).

Answer (score 2):

Your i is not initialized. Instead of making it i = 0, you do i < 0. And in the j loop, the maximum number should be d. So j < d. Not j <= d.

Comment: done with this question.how can i extend this program to print fibonacci series between two numbers?please give some idea

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating one element too few. Your code to delete `ar` never runs because it follows the return. You also leak `p` because you overwrite the pointer with that returned by `fib()`.

If I were you I would probably pass `p` to `fib()` and get `fib()` to fill out the array.

```
void fib(int n, int p[])
{
    p[0] = 1;
    p[1] = 1;
    for (int i=2; i<=n; i++)
        p[i] = p[i-2]+p[i-1];
}
```

Obviously this code requires `n>=2` but I will leave error checking as an exercise to the reader!

To call it use code like this:

```
int p[] = new int[count];
fib(count, p);
```

If you want to print out values between i1 and i2, say, do it like this:

```
for (int i=i1, i<=i2, i++)
    std::cout<<p[i]<<std::endl;
```

Since you are using C++, all this code would be simpler with the C++ vector class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly here:

```
int i;
for(i<0;i<=count;i++)
    std::cout<<p[i]<<std::endl;
```

You are not assigning i any start value. Change it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    std::cout << p[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: how can i extend this program to print fibonacci series between two numbers?please give some idea

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of fibonacci series, and I started mine off with a[0] = 1 and a[1] = 1. Fibonacci series normaly start with 0 and 1 but mine will start 1 and 1.

#include "stdafx.h"
`#include <iostream>`

using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
    int a[25];
    int i,j;
    int fib[25];
    int fibs;
    char z;

    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 1;


        fib[1] = a[0];
        fib[2] = a[1];
        fibs = 0;

    for ( i=2; i<25; i++ )
    {
        fibs = fib[1] + fib[2];
        fib[1] = fib[2];
        fib[2] = fibs;
        a[i] = fibs;
    }

    for(i=0; i<25; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]=" << a[i] << endl;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you allocate the array one element too short. The parameter in `new[]` is the number of elements, **not** the highest index.

Another problem is that you allocate the array in two places, but that only creates a memory leak and doesn't affect the result.

Comment: done with this question.how can i extend this program to print fibonacci series between two numbers?please give some idea

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to allocate `int *p=new int[count];` inside main, because you will recieve from the `fib` function a pointer to an already alocated memory.

Secondly, everything that is after a `return` statement is unreachable code, so you can either remove it, or move it before `return`.

Furthermore, if you delete the array inside `fib` function, you will return a null pointer.

And the main problem is at:

```
for(i<0;i<=count;i++)
```

whom correct for is:

```
for(i = 0; i <= count; i++)
```

Comment: done with this question.how can i extend this program to print fibonacci series between two numbers?please give some idea –

Comment: You must compute the series until you reach the first number, and then continue to compute and this time also store the values in the array until you reach the second number.  Being a series, you cannot begin with a random number (or you will need 2 beginning numbers)