# fibonacci series between two numbers

Tags: c++, fibonacci

```
#include<iostream>

int* fib(int);

int main()
{
    int count;
    std::cout<<"enter number upto which fibonacci series is to be printed"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>count;
    int *p=new int[count];
    p=fib(count);
    int i;
    for(i<0;i<=count;i++)
        std::cout<<p[i]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int* fib(int d)
{
    int *ar=new int[d];
    int p=-1,q=1,r;
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<=d;j++)
    {
        r=p+q;
        ar[j]=r;
        p=q;
        q=r;
    }
    return ar;
    delete ar;
}
```

this program is printing fibonacci series with given count in the series.please share some idea that how can i convert this program to find fibonacci series between two  numbers.

Comment: How many memory leaks and other bugs can you make in so little code? This code doesn't deserve to be called C++.

Comment: @Sjoerd we [discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927023) such issues with the same code already.

Comment: you received lots of criticism when you posted this code in another question today. Yet you post the same code without bothering to correct it - I'd say it is an abuse of the forum

Comment: sorry to all .next tym i will take care of these things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `(5*N*N + 4)` or `(5*N*N - 4)` for a given N >= 0  is a perfect square then the number is Fibonacci. Employ this method to generate Fibonacci series between two numbers.

Comment: Perhaps a link to an article explaining this would be helpful. And in my implementation I would use this technique until two numbers have been found and then switch to the normal `a,b=b,a+b` algorithm.

Comment: @nightcracker : Check out this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/checking-if-a-number-is-a-fibonacci-or-not